# Initiate empty Swift array of dictionaries

Tags: swift

I currently have this:

```
var locations = [
    ["location": "New York", "temp": "2 °C", "wind": "3 m/s"]
]
```

And I add stuff to this with `locations.append()`. It works great!

However, I don't want there to be a default entry. So I tried

```
var locations = [] // Not working.
var locations = [] as NSArray
var locations = [] as NSMutableArray
var locations = [] as NSDictionary
var locations = [] as NSMutableDictionary
var locations = [:] as ... everything
var locations = [APIData]
```

Feels like I've tried everything but I still get countless errors whatever I try. At this stage I'm even surprised my default locations is working.

How do I solve this? How do I make locations empty to start with?

Comment: var locations: [[String: String]] = [] ?

Comment: Please read the "Collection Types" chapter in the Swift language book. It clearly demonstrates how to create empty arrays/dictionaries/sets.

Comment: [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

Comment: If you're using Xcode, you can option-click on a variable to find out its type which gets you most of the way there.  In this case `[[String : String]]`.  One way to initialize is `var locations = [[String : String]]()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume you try to initialize a array of dictionary with key `String` and value `String` you should:

```
var locations: [[String: String]] = []
```

then you could do:

```
locations.append(["location": "New York", "temp": "2 °C", "wind": "3 m/s"])
```

Comment: @LeoDabus - Curious, why the edit? The original code was just fine. Two different ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To create an array or dictionary you should know the type you need.

With

```
var array: [String]
```

you declare a variable to contain an array of strings. To initialize it, you can use

```
var array: [String] = [String]()
```

You can omit the `: [String]` because the compiler can automatically detect the type in this case.

To create a dictionary you can do the same, but you need to define both, the key and the value type:

```
var dictionary = [String: String]()
```

Now, what you ask for is an array of dictionaries, so you need to combine both to

```
var arrayOfDictionaries = [[String: String]]()
```